# Find duplication from Excel 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need Excel VBA for the following

Sheet1: having 2 column (EmpCode, PFCode)

Sheet2: having 5 Columns (EmpCode, Name, Dateof Birth, PFCode, Remarks)

I need to check sheet1 Empcode & PFCode with Sheet2 EmpCode & PFCode and if both fiels matching in Sheet2 Remarks (Col5) is "Dup".

Please note in sheet1 more than 500 records and in sheet 2 more than 25000 records.

I need Excel VBA

Comment: countifs not working for you...?

Comment: There are some great tutorials and examples  available online. Search for something like  "use countifs and lookups to match data in Excel".

Comment: @user2579235, post your coding efforts along with minimal data samples to let people reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get a *faster* result by using the method in Jeeped's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079843/find-duplication-from-excel-2-sheets#comment85165631_49079843), but here is a VBA solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, x As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    speedUpCode

    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = ws2.Cells(x, 1) And ws1.Cells(i, 2) = ws2.Cells(x, 4) Then
                ws2.Cells(i, 5) = "Dup"
            End If
        Next x
    Next i

    speedUpCode False

End Sub

Sub speedUpCode(Optional bFlag As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        If bFlag = True Then
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        Else
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You can probably run this faster by adding this data to an array and compare the values there rather than reading line-by-line, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply.  But this is not working for me. The error message shows 'Microsoft Visual Basic - 400' message box

Comment: That would be due to the fact that I broke my #1 rule and didn't use `Option Explicit` at the top of my module. But while we are here, ensure that `Worksheets(1)` and `..(2)` are correct. Updated answer though.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Output Shows error.Below is output.
EmpCode Name DateofBirth PFCode Remarks
EMP104 E  PF104 Dup
EMP105 F  PF105 Dup
EMP105 F  PF105 
EMP107 H  PF107 Dup
EMP130 P  PF130 Dup
EMP114 O  PF114 

But I need output as follows
EmpCode Name DateofBirth PFCode Remarks
EMP104 E  PF104 Dup
EMP105 F  PF105 Dup
EMP105 F  PF105 Dup
EMP107 H  PF107 Dup
EMP130 P  PF130  (not available in sheet1)
EMP114 O  PF114 Dup
Please note in Sheet1 No duplicate records. But in Sheet2 duplicate records is available.